# REDIS SPOP not consistent in dynomite

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

I have a set in REDIS and I use SPOP and SADD to get and return elements to and from the set
I am using dynomite as a layer in front of REDIS and I have 2 DCs each DC with 1 rack and 1 node
when I execute SPOP on one node instead of removing the same element from the other node it just does SPOP again and then a second random element is removed from the SET

Am I not using it correctly or is this a bug in dynomite?

I would expect only one element to be removed and (The same one that was removed from the first node )

Comment: The way I delt with it was to use SRANDMEMBER to only get a member but not actually remove it, then I executed SREM for that specific element